# Invalid character "200b" in SQL query built from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am getting invalid character <200b> in SQL. How to get rid of it. I am so confused. Thanks for any help.

Below is the screen shot of oracle thrown error.

StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select oid, request_number, version_number, cust_req_number,  tot_route_dist from ( select Tab.oid,Tab.request_number,Tab.version_number,Tab.cust_req_number, Tab.tot_route_dist, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY cust_req_number order by Tab.updated_at)  seq_no from ( select t1.oid, t1.request_number,t1.version_number,t1.cust_req_number, t2.tot_route_dist, t1.updated_at from iclr_request t1,  iclr_summary_results t2 where t1.oid = t2.request_oid and t1.updated_by = 'iclear_self_fitness' and t1.status = 'Success' and t1.oid >= 30622 and t1.oid <= 30622 order by TO_NUMBER(t1.cust_req_number) ) Tab ) Tab1 where Tab1.seq_no = 1 order by TO_NUMBER(Tab1.cust_req_number)**<200b>**]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

I don't have any such character in java while constructing that SQL query. Below is screenshot of Java code that I have.

[image]

Comment: Copying and pasting the actual error and the actual code would have been better than supplying two screenshots, especially when one of them is almost completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Character 200b is a zero-width space.  You might be best just re-typing some or all of your SQL to get rid of it, because it can be difficult to find and delete otherwise.